# Две директивы в одном компоненте. Конфликт

Tags: angular, angular-directive, директива

Всем добрый день!

У меня задача загрузить два внешних модуля в одном компоненте. Загружаю внешними скриптами через директивы рендерингом. Проблема в том, что загружается только последний, первый при загрузке "затирается". Вижу, что все дело в рендеринге, когда создаю новый элемент. Как это исправить?

home.component.html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
  <searchTourSimple [script]="'src/app/scripts/homeSearch.js'"></searchTourSimple>
</div>
<div class="shop-window">
  <div id="shopwindow-container">
    <shopWindow [script]="'src/app/scripts/shopwindow.js'"></shopWindow>
  </div>
</div>
```

dir1.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'searchTourSimple'
})

export class SearchModuleSimpleDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('script') param: any
  script: any

  constructor(private renderer:Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.script = this.renderer.createElement('script')     
    this.script.type = 'text/javascript'    
    this.script.src = this.param
    this.script.async = true
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, this.script)

    document.write = function(input: string) {
      document.getElementById('home').innerHTML += input
    }
  }
}
```

dir2.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'shopWindow'
})

export class ShopWindowDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('script') param: any
  script: any

  constructor(private renderer:Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.script = this.renderer.createElement('script')
    this.script.type = 'text/javascript'
    this.script.src = this.param
    this.script.async = true
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.head, this.script)

    document.write = function(input: string) {
      document.getElementById('shopwindow-container').innerHTML += input
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: что это `document.write = function(input: string) ` ?

Comment: input - это и есть  модуль

Comment: Еще заметил такую вещь: вторая директива выполняется два раза. Сначала почему-то загружает повторно первый модуль, а потом уже второй. Это видно из консоли:

Comment: какой модуль? и почему `input` это модуль, если это параметр типа стринг?

Comment: Это результат выполнения скрипта, iframe, который нужно вставить в DOM, что я и делаю функцией document.write

Comment: а зачем вам вообще этот велосипед?

Comment: А есть вариант лучше? Просто только так я смог вставить модуль в нужное место в разметке, иначе он просто плюхается в нулевые координаты поверх всей разметки.

Comment: в смысле "вариант лучше"? я даже не знаю что вы пытаетесь реализовать) к тому же патчите нативную функцию, что не есть хорошо)

Comment: Мне нужно получить сторонний программный модуль от стороннего разработчика. В другом фреймворке я бы просто открыл тэг <script> в нужном месте разметки и вставил туда скрипт разрабов, но ангуляр игнорит все такие тэги в компонентах (вопрос - зачем?), вот и приходится выпендриваться. Другого способа как это реализовать я пока не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема связана с тем, что вторая директива также патчит `document.write`, тем самым первая директива использует уже метод, запатченный второй директивой и сеттит `innerHTML` в `document.getElementById('shopwindow-container')`.

Вам не нужны здесь директивы, если я правильно понял из исходного кода, то вы с помощью директив пытаетесь грузить внешние `.js` ресурсы, вам нужно вообще изолировать эту бизнес логику в какой-то сервис, назовем его `ScriptService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ScriptService {
    private loadResource(src: string): Observable<void> {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');

            script.async = true;
            script.src = src;

            script.addEventListener('load', () => {
                observer.next();
                observer.complete();
            });

            document.head.appendChild(script);
        });
    }

    private patchDocumentWrite(id: string): void {
        document.write = (input: string): void => {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += input;
        };
    }

    public loadExternalResources(): Observable<void> {
        return of(null).pipe(
            tap(() => this.patchDocumentWrite('home')),
            switchMap(() => this.loadResource('src/app/scripts/homeSearch.js')),
            tap(() => this.patchDocumentWrite('shopwindow-container')),
            switchMap(() => this.loadResource('src/app/scripts/shopwindow.js'))
        );
    }
}
```

Что мы делаем? Метод `loadResource` возвращает поток и сгенерирует событие после полной загрузки внешнего ресурса (`onload`). `patchDocumentWrite` - просто патчит `document.write`, а аргументом принимает идентификатор элемента, в который нужно засеттить `innerHTML`. В методе `loadExternalResources` мы создаем пустой поток (нужен для последующего пайпинга). Перед загрузкой скрипта `homeSearch` патчим `document.write` и точно также дальше.

В данной реализации мы загружаем скрипты один за другим, но это дает нам гарантию, что какая-то директива не запатчит метод быстрее другой. Также не используем `Renderer2` (он не для этого нужен). Теперь нам нужно подписаться на поток, который возвращает метод `loadExternalResources`, чтобы запустить весь пайплайн, можем сделать это в `ngAfterViewInit` рут компонента:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private scriptService: ScriptService) {}

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.scriptService.loadExternalResources().subscribe(() => {
            console.log('все скрипты загрузились');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Все работает. Пробовал что-то подобное реализовывать, но без observable, в итоге ничего не вышло. Скажите, а для других компонентов свои сервисы лучше реализовать (тот же функционал, только модули другие)? И где можно почитать о всех этих методах next, complete, tap и др.?

Comment: всю "такую" логику лучше держать в сервисах, это обычная декомпозиция + single responsibility, почитать можно [тут](https://www.learnrxjs.io/). пометите ответ галочкой?

Comment: Обязательно. Такую - это в смысле загрузка внешних ресурсов?